# How to disable navigation keys in Vim?

Tags: keyboard, vim, text-editors, vimrc, keyboard-navigation

I want to disable the usual keys to navigate on a text editor that is the <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, and <kbd>Right</kbd> buttons in Vim text editor.

It would enforce the vim-style <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> keys to be used for the same purpose.

> I just want to train myself, haha.

I guess it might be done through mapping those keys to *nothing* in `vimrc`

Comment: "haha" but train yourself to what?

Comment: using the "[right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys#HJKL_keys)" (traditional, orthodox, older, vim-style) keys for text-navigation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: it can be done by mapping those keys to nothing, or to be precise, to `<Nop>`.

```
:nmap <Up> <Nop>
:nmap <Down> <Nop>
:nmap <Left> <Nop>
:nmap <Right> <Nop>
```

See

```
:help <Nop>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all who would like to take this approach one step forward: https://github.com/takac/vim-hardtime

It basically limits hjkl movements, so moving around with something like jjjjjjjjjhhkkkkkkk will not be possible, which is a real trap to fall into once you get used to those keys. If enforces you to move around more efficiently instead of redundant repetitions.

It can be toggled on/off anytime.

Comment: Oh my god that is evil. I like you.

Comment: Thanks, I also disabled the conventional Page Navigation buttons, to rely on Ctrl D and Ctrl U and other native Vim shortcuts :)